# this function highlight selected text, how can i delete the span made by javascript clicking the highlighted text?

Tags: javascript, highlight, html

I found this javascript code to highlight selected text, **how can i add a function to delete the highlight background (deleting the span that was created) just clicking the highlighted text?**

```
highlight=function()
    {       
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
    }
```

Comment: Why did you post the duplicate question?

Comment: because i dont want change the background to transparent, i wanna delete the span who make the background in my function

Comment: Why did you accept that answer then?

Comment: Sorry im new in here, Sergio if you can please help me with my question, thanks

Comment: See my comments to the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.highlight = function() {
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    span.onclick = function (ev) {
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(
            document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML), 
            this
        );
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
    selection.insertNode(span);
}
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FLwxj/1/)