# Insert character at specific point but preserving tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Update #2

Okay, more testing ensues. It looks like the code works fine when I use a faux spacer, but the regex eventually fails. Specifically, the following scenarios work:

1. Select words above or below the `a` tag
2. You select only one line either directly above or below the `a` tag
3. You select more than one line above/below the `a` tag
4. You select more than one line specifically below any `a` tag

The following scenarios do not work:

3. You select the line/more lines above the `a` tag, and then the line/more lines below the `a` tag

What happens when it "doesn't work" is that it removes the `a` tag spacer from the DOM. This is probably a problem with the regex...

**Basically**, it fails when you select text around the `a` tag.

---

### Update:

I don't need to wrap each line in a `p` tag, I can instead use an inline element, such as an `a`, `span`, or `label` tag, with `display:inline-block` and a height + width to act as a new line element (`<br />`). This should make it easier to modify the code, as the only part that should have to change is where I get the text in between the bounds. I should only have to change that part, `selectedText.textContent`, to retrieve the HTML that is also within the bounds instead of just the text.

---

I am creating a Phonegap that requires the user to select text. I need fine control over the text selection, however, and can no longer plop the entire text content in a `pre` styled `p` tag. Instead, I need represent a linebreak with something like `<a class="space"></a>`, so that the correct words can be highlighted precisely. When my text looks like this:

```
<p class="text">This is line one

Line two

Line three
</p>
```

And has `.text{ white-space:pre-wrap }`, the following code allows me to select words, then wrap the text with `span` elements to show that the text is highlighted:

```
$("p").on("copy", highlight);

function highlight() {
    var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span = $("<span class='highlight'>" + selectedText.textContent + "</span>");
    selection.insertNode(span[0]);
    if (selectedText.childNodes[1] != undefined) {
        $(selectedText.childNodes[1]).remove();
    }
    var txt = $('.text').html();
    $('.text').html(txt.replace(/<\/span>(?:\s)*<span class="highlight">/g, ''));
    $(".output ul").html("");
    $(".text .highlight").each(function () {
        $(".output ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
    });
    clearSelection();
}

function clearSelection() {
    if (document.selection) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

This code works beautifully, but not when each line is separated by a spacer tag. The new text looks like this:

```
<p class="text">
    Line one
    <a class="space"></a>
    Line two
    <a class="space"></a>
    Line three
</p>
```

When I modify the above code to work with have new lines represented by `<a class="space"></a>`, the code fails. It only retrieves the text of the selection, and not the HTML (`selectedText.textContent`). I'm not sure if the regex will also fail with an `a` element acting as a new line either. The `a` element could be a `span` or `label`, or any normally inline positioned element, to trick iOS into allowing me to select letters instead of block elements.

Is there anyway to change the code to preserve the new line elements?

### jsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/39TZ9/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/39TZ9/2/)

#### The desired output should look like this:

If the text "Line one" was highlighted:

```
<p class="text">
    <span class="highlight">Line one</span>
    <a class="space"></a>
    Line two
    <a class="space"></a>
    Line three
</p>
```

If the text "Line one Line two" was highlighted:

```
<p class="text">
    <span class="highlight">Line one
    <a class="space"></a>
    Line two</span>
    <a class="space"></a>
    Line three
</p>
```

Of course different parts and individual letters can and will be highlighted as well instead of full lines.

Comment: One thing that popups up immediately, is the different types of quotes will not trigger a match in the regex. The first `highlight` uses single quotes, and the second double. Probably won't fix your problem though.

Comment: That's not a problem because it is inserted as double quotes. I'm only using single quotes so I don't have to escape double quotes within double quotes.

Comment: I updated with an example

Comment: different line of thinking...  place a special class of bookend span before beginning and after end of current selection. Then use Jquery to search the full html of div and check for parent of bookend span class. Then some rules would be if preselected span only has one bookend span, the other bookend is in another paragraph, or if a previously selected span has 2 bookend spans...remove the bookends,  etc etc. Not sure if this idea helps or not.Not 100% clear what output format needs to be

Comment: @charlietfl Could you post an example? I'm having some trouble trying to follow you. And what do you mean by the output format?

Comment: by `ouput format` i mean are you trying to keep `<p>` tags as line breaks if selection spans multiple lines?

Comment: Yes, I am. I don't think it's valid, but I would just have the span tag start within one section, and end somewhere in the next section of p tag.

Comment: @charlietfl I added a more robust example of the output in the question.

Comment: not vallid having single span start in one `p` and end in another. Here's a proof of concept demo of my bookend idea . Code is still pretty rough but might help you http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5UnH/

Comment: revision http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5UnH/1/

Comment: @charlietfl Definitely a start. Now all that has to happen is have it handle having multiple book ends either inside the current selection, or having one immediately before/immediately after the beginning and end book end. As for the selection, I suppose it could just put the bookends in on "copy" at the beginning and end of the selection.

Comment: would remove bookends every time `copy` clicked, so only ever have one set. Will get a bit trickier sorting out bookends inside other `highlight` class but i think not too hard to create logic with jQuery.

Comment: Okay. Do you think it's possible without using Regex?

Comment: i am weak with regex and defintiely think it's possible without it. Just a matter of developing the other scenarios for overlapping selections by expanding on what I started

Comment: @charlietfl Plus it would need to add the bookends at the beginning and end of the selection. But, honestly, that method doesn't make much sense. Why not just add the beginning highlight `span` tag in the beginning of the selection, then add the closing tag at the end of the selection, preserving the html within?

Comment: because a span can't open in one paragraph and close in another and you can't find beginning and end tags in a DOM search. Some browsers like IE would likely rearrange the element because it's not valid that way. Can only find the complete element represented by start/end tags

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought that even though it wouldn't be valid, a span tag could span between two `p` elements. Your method should work then... any luck on getting it to work with the other requirements?

Comment: wasn't planning on doing much more with it honestly...  will take a fair bit of time getting all the scenarios covered and then refctoring code to be more compact

Comment: I'm not really sure how to continue with your method, but I'll gladly award you the bounty if you can get a working example. In the mean time, I'll continue to work on it too...

Comment: @charlietfl Major update, check the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I came up with *a* solution, rather straightforward as well.

If `.text` looks like this:

```
<p class="text">Line one
<a class="space"></a>Line two
<a class="space"></a>Line three</p>
```

With the exact markup and line breaks as above, then I can find each `\n` and replace it with a spacer element.

```
if (textStr.indexOf("\n") >= 0) {
    textStr = textStr.replace(/\n/g, "\n<a class='space'></a>");
}
```

This isn't versatile at all, and will fail if there are more than one line breaks, if the tags are different, etc. So, I encourage anyone who has a better method to answer the question! It can't be that hard, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that supports all the features from your requirements:

**HTML**:

```
<p class="text">
    First Line
    <a class="space"></a>
    <a class="space"></a>
    Second Line
    <span class="space"></span>
    Third Line
    <label class="space"></label>
    Forth Line
</p>
<ul class="output"></ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.space {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.highlighting {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var text,
    output,
    unwrapContents,
    mergeElements,
    clearSelection,
    clearHighlighting,
    mergeHighlighting,
    handleCopy;

unwrapContents = function unwrapContents(element) {
    while(element.firstChild !== null) {
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(element.firstChild, element);
    }
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
};

mergeElements = function mergeElements(startElement, endElement) {
    var currentElement;
    endElement = endElement.nextSibling;
    while((currentElement = startElement.nextSibling) !== endElement) {
        startElement.appendChild(currentElement);
    }
};

clearSelection = function clearSelection() {
    if (document.selection) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
};

clearHighlighting = function clearHighlighting(target, exception) {
    $('.highlighting', target).each(function(index, highlighting) {
        if(highlighting !== exception) {
            unwrapContents(highlighting);
        }
    });
    target.normalize();
};

mergeHighlighting = function mergeHighlighting() {
    var i, j;
    // Remove internal highlights
    $('.highlighting', text).filter(function() {
        return this.parentNode.className === 'highlighting';
    }).each(function(index, highlighting) {
        unwrapContents(highlighting);
    });
    text.normalize();
    // Merge adjacent highlights
    first:
    for(i=0; i<text.childNodes.length-1; i++) {
        if(text.childNodes[i].className === 'highlighting') {
            for(j=i+1; j<text.childNodes.length; j++) {
                if(text.childNodes[j].className === 'highlighting') {
                    mergeElements(text.childNodes[i], text.childNodes[j--]);
                    unwrapContents(text.childNodes[i].lastChild);
                } else {
                    switch(text.childNodes[j].nodeType) {
                        case 1:
                            if(text.childNodes[j].className !== 'space') {
                                continue first;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if(text.childNodes[j].textContent.trim() !== '') {
                                continue first;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

handleCopy = function handleCopy() {
    var range,
        highlighting,
        item;

    // Highlighting
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    highlighting = document.createElement('span');
    highlighting.className = 'highlighting';
    highlighting.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(highlighting);

    // Output
    item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerHTML = highlighting.innerHTML;
    clearHighlighting(item);
    output.appendChild(item);

    // Cleanup
    mergeHighlighting();
    clearSelection();
};

$(function(){
    text = $('.text')[0];
    output = $('.output')[0];
    $(text).on('copy', handleCopy);
});
```

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/efohit/3/edit

Comment: Not true. This doesn't include options for merging highlights on overlap, and only presents one highlight on the screen at a time.

Comment: @Charlie I updated the implementation. Now adjacent, overlapping and nested highlights are merged.

Comment: How does this compare to my code, that was for some reason row voted?