# Get text selected and update him

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very large text inside a textarea with a button , all I want to do is :

1 - Once this button is clicked , automatically take the jquery part of the text that the User selected with the mouse and create 2 tags around text in this textarea

*example :*

**Existing text in the text area :**

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry . Lorem Ipsum has been the industry 's standard dummy text
>   ever since the 1500s , When an unknown printer took a galley of type
>   and scrambled it to make a type specimen book . It has survived not
>   only five centuries , but Also the leap into electronic typesetting ,
>   remaining Essentially unchanged . It was popularized in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages , and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum .

**Text selected by the mouse :**

> 1500s , When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
>   to make a type specimen book . It has survived not only five centuries
>   , but Also the leap into electronic typesetting ,

**What would happen once the button is clicked :**

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the ***[INFO]1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
>   and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
>   only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
>   typesetting,[/INFO]*** remaining essentially unchanged. It was
>   popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
>   containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
>   publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
>   Ipsum.

I don't tryed anything, but i don't know who pick the selected text, and update him into the textarea.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any code to share with us?  Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you share that with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could use something like jQuery's `replace()` function, that would only replace the first instance of whatever you've highlighted, not the actual highlighted content. You can remedy this by getting the bounds of the selection, however, and splitting the string accordingly:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
        text = "[INFO]" + selection + "[/INFO]",
        content = $("div").text(),
        range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
        startText = content.substring(0, range.startOffset), // cut from 0 to beginning of highlight
        endText = content.substring(range.endOffset, content.length); // cut from end of highlight to end of text
    $("div").html(startText + text + endText);
});
```

This will sometimes get more complicated however, [as I've previously discussed at length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733349/insert-character-at-specific-point-but-preserving-tags).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/a34Rk/1/)